# How to map CMD+P to CTRL+P without actually modifiying CMD from root

Tags: vim, macvim

I want to map <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> => <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in vim. How can I do this? I tried doing

```
 map <D-P> <C-P>
```

But this doesn't seem to work, it is still firing `print` command.

PS: I know i can do this with **BetterTouchTool** but it is kindof hack. Isn't possible with vim configuration ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first you have to remove default mapping, you could do it in `~/.gvimrc` file by the following:

```
macmenu File.Print key=<nop>
```

then, you can just map it as usual

Comment: Take a look at `:h cmd-key` and `:h macvim` for more information